# Email not send using Codelgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to send an email to the user who is verified by the Admin. When the admin clicks on verify button in DB the status of a user is changed and email sends to a user, status can change but the email not send.

AdminController:

```
if($this->AdminModel->updateUser($id , $status)){

            $user_message = "hello";

            $this->load->library('email');

            $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';

            $config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';

            $config['smtp_port']    = '465';

            $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';

            $config['smtp_user']    = 'kshahroz699@gmail.com';

            $config['smtp_pass']    = 'password';

            $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';

            $config['newline']    = "\r\n";

            $config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // or html

            $config['validation'] = TRUE;

            $this->email->initialize($config);

            $this->email->from('kshahroz699@gmail.com', 'Model Hunt Inquiry');
            $this->email->to($email);
            $this->email->subject('Model Hunt Inquiry Form');
            $this->email->message($user_message);
            if($this->email->send()) {
                echo " Successfully send";
            }else{
                echo "Not Send";
            }
```

AdminModel:

```
function updateUser($id, $data){
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        return $this->db->update('mh_users',$data);
    }
```

Route:

```
$route['verifyUserEmail/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Admin/verifyEmail/$1/$2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Admin Model

```
function updateUser($id, $data){
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    return $this->db->update('mh_users',$data);
}
```

My Controller

```
  $this->load->library('email'); 

    if($this->AdminModel->updateUser($id , $status)){

        $from   =   'no-reply@test.com';
        $to = 'test@gmail.com';
        $message1 = 'Hello Test';

        $config = array();
        $config['useragent'] = "CodeIgniter";
        $config['mailpath'] = "/usr/bin/sendmail"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
        $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
        $config['smtp_host'] = "localhost";
        $config['smtp_port'] = "25";
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
        $config['newline']  = "\r\n";
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from($from, 'Test');
        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->subject('Test');
        $this->email->message($message1);
        $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
        if($this->email->send()){
            $message=array("1","Mail Sent Successfully");
        }else{
            $message=array("0",$this->db->_error_message());
        }
    }
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $message);
```